# Monitor USB IO "traffic" (in whatever language)

Tags: java, c, windows, usb, monitor

I'm wondering if I can monitor the I/O of a USB, for instance:

```
[Ask] PC->Port 1: Requesting contents of "D:\folder\file.txt"
[Res] Port 1->PC: File exists, <response>

[Ask] PC->Port 1: Copy "C:\folder\file2.txt" to "D:\folder\file2.txt"
[Ask] Port 1->PC: Requesting contents of "C:\folder\file2.txt"
[Res] ... etc. You get the idea
```

I'd prefer if I could do this in Java, but any variant of C would be acceptable as well.

Is there any way of accomplishing this? And if this isn't how USBs work, then I'm a complete idiot, which would make sense.

Comment: Does it have to be USB? Would logging the WinAPI calls for copying work?

Comment: Did you check `usbpcap` out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this level.

[You can monitor USB traffic using Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB), but the operations you see will be at a **MUCH** lower level than you're imagining here. USB mass storage devices aren't aware of high-level abstractions like files or copying data; the operations they deal with are primarily oriented around reading and writing data at specific locations within the device.

(Incidentally, this means that USB storage devices are not involved in file copies in the way you're imagining. The computer is fully in control of file copies, and will make them happen by writing data to the USB device. The USB device will never request files from the computer; it doesn't even have any way of asking for that.)

A more appropriate tool for your needs might be [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), which will allow you to monitor Windows API calls. This is still probably a lower-level view than you will be expecting, but it will at least display operations in terms of files.